# How does array_udiff() work?

Tags: php

Here's the code, it's very simple:

```
<?php
$tab = array (
    (object)array( 'id' => 1,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 4,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 12,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 22,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 25,),
);

$tab_json = array (
    (object)array( 'id' => 1,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 4,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 12,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 22,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 25,),
    (object)array( 'id' => 2,),
);
$difference = array_udiff($tab_json, $tab, function($a, $b) {
    echo $a->id." <-> ".$b->id."\n";
    return (count(array_diff_assoc(get_object_vars($a), get_object_vars($b))))>0;
});
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
12 <-> 4
12 <-> 1
12 <-> 22
12 <-> 25
2 <-> 12
4 <-> 25
4 <-> 1
22 <-> 4
25 <-> 1
12 <-> 4
12 <-> 1
12 <-> 22
25 <-> 12
4 <-> 22
1 <-> 4
1 <-> 22
1 <-> 4
1 <-> 1
1 <-> 25
25 <-> 4
25 <-> 1
25 <-> 12
25 <-> 25
25 <-> 4
4 <-> 1
4 <-> 12
4 <-> 25
4 <-> 22
22 <-> 1
22 <-> 12
22 <-> 25
22 <-> 12
12 <-> 1
12 <-> 12
12 <-> 2
2 <-> 12
2 <-> 25
```

I don't understand how it's computed: look at `12`: it's compared more than 10 times (whereas, from what I understand, it should be compared no more than the number of elements of the second array), and moreover it's compared three times with `1`!

Tested on:

```
PHP 5.3.9
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14
```

Comment: You're confusing the comparison by not returning any negative values from your callback. It should return pos/zero/neg as per the [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) docs. And if you're trying to figure out the operational characteristics, you should go look at the PHP source to get the 'official' word.

Comment: I'm asking this question because I'd like people (like me) getting things done faster thanks to stackoverflow. This implies avoiding looking at the PHP source to get the 'official' word, and asking if someone here is willing to share his/her knowledge.

Comment: You could add you remark as an answer though, and modify my code to make it more "logical". That would be very kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `array_udiff()` actually produces its result is of course an implementation detail and subject to change. So while what I say might be true right now, you must not rely on it.

For instance, if you need to use an old version of PHP, you might well implement a compatibility version of the function which simply compares each element of the first array against each element of the second array, discarding any that match.

On the other hand, if you want the most performance, you would quicksort the elements of the second array, and then perform a binary search of the elements of the first array.

PHP 5.3 seems to combine a quicksort with a linear search. It does however abort the search once it's found a larger element.

Comment: So, in my sample, how shall I do to compare objects and their properties?

Comment: == should be enough to compare objects, like the sample I give you in the other question. Though, if your objects are more complex than structures with public properties, you should consider this complexity. See a sample http://tehplayground.com/#GyUaoV1Cy